# ReactJS Context re-render after a fetch with useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to pass data with my `context provider` through the entire application but the hook that triggers, only returns it's initial value and **doesn't re-trigger**.

This is my application layout inside my main `App` component which doesn't hold any state.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <UserContextProvider>
            <div className="container">
              <Header />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/secret-page" component={SecretPage} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </UserContextProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Whenever the `App` component renders for the first time, it triggers the `UserContextProvider` which fires an `onEffect` hook. This hook tries to **fetch** some data but since the user is not logged in, it just returns it's original value `[]`.

Here is the **Context Provider**

```
const UserContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [userSettings, setUserSettings] = useState([]);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userid !== null) {
      fetch(
        process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/authenticated/get-permissions",
        requestOptions
      )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          setUserSettings(response.data);
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    } else {
      console.log(userSettings);
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={userSettings}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now when the code above fires initially, the `userid` value is `null` but after authentication in the `LoginPage` child component, it changes to a token. My issue is that even though `userid`'s value changes after login, the hook doesn't fire again.

I just want to mention that I get the `userid` value from local storage in a separate file and import it.

I've tried setting the `userid` value in the empty array argument inside the function but that doesn't work.

How can I make my `useEffect` hook to fire again after the `userid` value has changed?

--- EDIT-----

`userid` is import from another file called `fetchRequestOptions` in this way:

```
import {requestOptions, userid} from "./fetchRequestOptions";
```

Inside my `fetchRequestOptions` file I have the following code:

```
let userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");
let accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accesstoken");
let requestOptions ={ <my request options are here>}
```

Comment: where is `userid` coming from? I can't seem to find it in your Context Provider code example. Is it a prop? Is it defined outside of the provider?

Comment: @Daniel made an edit and updated my code.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the hook that uses `userid` to re-run when it changes, you need to keep it inside a state. Then, `LoginPage` needs to be connected to the Context and use `setUserid` to update its value.

```
const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [userSettings, setUserSettings] = useState([]);
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    // If you are reading directly from localstorage you might
    // want to use localStorage.getItem("userid") as the initial value
    const [userid, setUserid] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // ...
    }, [userid]);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ userSettings, setUserid }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

The key is that `userid` needs to be inside a state, this way it can trigger a new render in any Component where you need its latest value.

You might find it cleaner to have a specific custom hook, inside your Context, that handles the logic for the userid (fetch and update). This is a good option but it only makes `userid` available inside this context. If you need to use it somewhere else you will need to export it from the context `value` prop.

```
const useUserid = () => {
    const [userid, setUserid] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetched_userid = //...
        setUserid(fetched_userid);
    }, []);

    return userid;
};

const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    // ...
    const userid = useUserid();

    useEffect(() => {
        // ...
    }, [userid]);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={userSettings}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Comment: so how do I get the values from `userSettings` in this case? Because if I do this and `console.log(userSettings)`, I just print the function call.

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard, the context value now is an object with 2 properties: `{ userSettings, setUserid }`. Depending of the initial value you give to `const [userid, setUserid] = useState(null)` the first call of the hook will use a userid or use `null`. Let me know if Im not clear.

Comment: so if I want to access the data inside `userSettings` from the context in any other page, should I just specify it as `const userSettings = useContext(UserSettings)` ?

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard, the return from useContext is the object I was talking about. So: `const { userSettings, setUserid } = useContext(UserContext)`. The key is that userid needs to be inside a state. You might find it cleaner to have it somewhere else though, as long as it is passed to the context `useEffect`.

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard I added some examples in the answer. Please see if those help.

Comment: I tried implementing the custom hook in the file `fetchRequestOptions ` where I actually obtain the value but I still can't force a re-render of the `Context Provider`.

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard. Id say the easiest way in this case is to set the `userid` state inside the Context. And then import `setUserid` from the Context where you want to update it.

Comment: I'm still struggling to implement this because I can't use a hook inside a callback and I'm setting the `userid` inside a callback function. But I think your advice was really helpful and it's the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an empty array [] in an useEffect hook means that (as per React documentation)

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run

So, we need to pass props/state that acts as trigger for effect to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

pass `userid` as an argument in the dependency array of the useEffect. This ensures the effect is run whenever `userid` changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
   ...
  }, [userid]);
```